# How to link external CSS stylesheets on a Chromebook

Tags: html, css, chrome-dev-editor

I'm developing a website and I need to use external CSS stylesheets.
The only drawback is I'm using a new Chromebook after migrating from Windows.

I'm using CDE, so how should I link an external stylesheet to an HTML file?
To be more specific, how do I find the full file path of a CSS file on a Chromebook?

Comment: @AMADANONInc. I've tried using the file path in CDE shown in properties, and I've tried uploading the file to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For all of the noobs out there, I figured it out.

You have to link an external stylesheet (if on a Chromebook) using relative linking, so what you will want to do is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="name_of_stylesheet_in_same_folder_as_html.css">
```

Basically, keep your CSS file in the same folder as your HTML or Javascript file and it will most likely work when there is no standard full file path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you view the css directly in the browser? If so, whatever url you're using should work. If not, perhaps something else is going on. Chromebook should be no different from any other browser.

Comment: Turns out it is. It gives me something like this when I open it in a browser: http://127.0.0.1:51792/my-little-octocat/index.html

Comment: You need to upload it to some sort of hosting first.  I have used google drive before, and it works rather well.